# Why does this script not reliably log the latest file?

Tags: bash

This script fails sometimes and succeeds sometimes (a very annoying situation):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuxo pipefail

test_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
touch "$test_dir/file"{001..312}
latest_file="$(find $test_dir -type f | sort -r | head -n1)"
echo $latest_file
```

When it succeeds, it logs something like this:

```
++ mktemp -d
+ test_dir=/tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7
+ touch /tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file001 /tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file002 ... /tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file312
++ find /tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7 -type f
++ head -n1
++ sort -r
+ latest_file=/tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file312
+ echo /tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file312
/tmp/tmp.yWelcpBYB7/file312
```

When it fails, it logs something like this:

```
++ mktemp -d
+ test_dir=/tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG
+ touch /tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG/file001 /tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG/file002 ... /tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG/file312
++ find /tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG -type f
++ sort -r
++ head -n1
+ latest_file=/tmp/tmp.VzTqmgpZyG/file312
```

Notice that `echo $latest_file` line is **not** executed here even though it appears in xtrace

I cannot get a successful run if I use 10,000 files, so I suspect it has something to do with **head** stopping **find** early.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuxo pipefail

test_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
touch "$test_dir/file"{0000..9999}
latest_file="$(find $test_dir -type f | sort -r | head -n1)"
echo $latest_file
```

If I suppress stop on error (using **set +e**), it succeeds:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuxo pipefail

test_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
touch "$test_dir/file"{0000..9999}
set +e
latest_file="$(find $test_dir -type f | sort -r | head -n1)"
set -e
echo $latest_file
```

Why does this script not reliably log the latest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `-e`. Why? `-e` makes bash abort in case a process exits with a non-zero exit code (the full rules are a bit more complicated). If there is a pipe, just the last command counts.

Your `head -n1` creates an error situation, internally, because it has to kind of break the pipe (you can check it with `strace`) to ignore the rest of the output from `sort`.

So, to make your script work reliably with `-e`, you can add a `cat` to the end of the pipe. `head` will still break the pipe, but since it no longer is the last command in it, it will not be taken into account by `-e`. `cat` is a no-op for the pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuxo pipefail

test_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
touch "$test_dir/file"{0000..9999}
latest_file="$(find $test_dir -type f | sort -r | head -n1 | cat)"
echo $latest_file
```

Please check [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) to know why `-e` is such an unstable feature and the kind of problems it might bring about. There are many examples at the end. My favorite:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
foo=$(expr 1 - 1)
echo survived
```

It will **not** print *survived*, that line will not be executed. But, if you had `foo=$(expr 2 - 1)`, then the `echo` would be executed!

You'd be better off implementing your own error checking, `-e` isn't the best solution out there.

Comment: `| cat` didn't work in my case (Amazon Linux 2 possible kernel differences, who knows), but your explanation of why my script is non-deterministic is really helpful, especially the BashFAQ reference you linked to. I've suppressed errors around the problematic line with `set +e` and `set -e` now.